# How to get the all the points under the finger which has touched

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

When a finger is touched over the screen, i need all the points which were touched. basically it gives only the centre of the touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You could take the center and select all pixel in a circle with a radius of 44 pixels, which should roughly be the touched pixel.

Comment: I take it this wouldn't be the same number with the different pixel densities across different iOS devices?